# Is there a way to start the tick() loop on a pooled A-Frame entity, or should I manage that manually?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm using A-Frame and trying to generate pool multiple 'cloud' entities that will slowly begin moving in a particular direction once activated, but the `tick()` function doesn't seem to be being called! Is there a way to kickstart it, or do I need to manage it manually?

Here's the setup that I'm using to test with 1 cloud:

**HTML**

```
<a-assets>
    <a-mixin id="cloud" cloud></a-mixin>
</a-assets>

<a-entity 
    cloudmanager
    pool="mixin: cloud; size: 1;">
</a-entity>
```

**cloudmanager.js**

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("cloudmanager", {
    init: function(){
        const cloudEl = this.el.components.pool.requestEntity();
        cloudEl.components.cloud.startMoving();
    }
});
```

**cloud.js**

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("cloud", {

    //LIFECYCLE
    //-----------
    init: function(){
        this.startMoving = this.startMoving.bind(this);
        this.moving      = false;
       // ...and then create the cloud geometry etc etc
    },
    tick: function(time, deltaTime){
        console.log("tick"); //never happens!

        if(this.moving) this.move(deltaTime);
    },

    //UTILS
    //-----------
    startMoving: function(){
        console.log("starting to move!"); //logs ok
        this.moving = true;
    },
    move: function(deltaTime){
       // translations etc etc
    }
});
```

The cloud gets created okay (confirmed with logging and appears in scene), it gets told to start moving okay (confirmed with logging), but the `console.log` inside `tick()` just never fires and so I can't get the cloud moving!

Am I not using the pool correctly? Or is this just an optimisation so that pooled entities aren't all ticking even when they're not used? Do I need to activate them in some way?

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks all.

-p

Answer (score 1):

You can try moving the manager component to initialize after the pool is initialized:

```
<a-entity 
  pool="mixin: cloud; size: 1;"
  cloudmanager>
</a-entity>
```

And it should be working. Check it out in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/roychud8/2/) fiddle.

---

The pool component will call `play` and `pause` upon requesting and returning entities. When an element is requested, the `tick` function should be called on each frame.

Comment: Hmmm, alas - no joy, How strange! I'm using `aframe-react` and I've been getting nothing but problems with that, so there might be things I can do in that regard. Fortunately this isn't game-breaking as I can just manage it myself, but it is strange and a bit annoying! haha.

Comment: A minimal react example on glitch would help a bit with troubleshooting if you can provide one :)